# Number of custom domains supported by a GAE app instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I am wondering if there's a limit to how many custom domains an AppEngine application can have? I am creating a service where I would like to allow customers to point their domain to my app (GAE-java), and I'll use URL rewriting to serve content for the customer -- I know right now I have to manually add the domain (as in [Many Custom Domains for AppEngine Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990041/many-custom-domains-for-appengine-instance)) but I am not expecting high volume and don't have the resources to setup a reverse proxy.

What are the potential gotchas? I know there's a limit of SSL certificates I can install per account, so I'd have problems if I need to support HTTPS for the custom domains, but anything else? Or perhaps I should look into services like cloudflare to go on top?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit for the number of domains an App Engine application can have. SSL support will be a bit tricky, but not impossible. Domain owners must setup SSL for their domains themselves. Hint: App Engine application paying for the SSL support may be different from the application served from the domain.

Comment: Looks like this is not the case anymore. App Engine only allows maximum 20 custom domains. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains